# How to travel to and within the EU with a small dog from Canada?

Tags: air-travel, eu, pets

I am a Canadian who recently got his UK passport. I'm planning on going to Poland from Canada at the start of January. I will be taking my small dog with me. He's 10 lb and is very quiet and well behaved.

What I do know is that I have to make sure I have all of his shots up to date for traveling on a plane and for the country I'm going to. I'll have to call the airline and country (embassy? I'm not sure who to call) ahead of time to inform them I will be bringing my dog.

I've read about an EU passport for your pet but it doesn't look like I can get that until I'm in Europe.

Is there anything I can do to make traveling to Europe and within Europe with my dog easier? Is there a passport I can get for him? Is traveling from Poland to Germany going to be easy as long as I have his documentation?

Comment: Your vet might have a dog passport, in which he can/should note all shots your dog has had recently and will get before traveling. I think it is the same as the European one you mention. And before you book a place to stay, check whether they accept pets. Some places do not due to other people being allergic, not because of the way the dog behaves. (Comment as I am not sure about the dog passport.)

Comment: Microchip him if he isn't already.

Answer (score 1):

The [Government of Canada](https://travel.gc.ca/travelling/documents/animals-certificate) details what you would need:

> **Travel documents for your pets**
>
> Before you leave Canada, contact the embassy of your destination country about its requirements for importing animals.
>
> The Canadian International Health Certificate may be used to accompany pet dogs and cats to other countries. This certificate must be printed on legal paper (8.5" X 14"). No other format will be accepted.
>
> Bilingual - [Canadian International Health Certificate - PDF (178 kb)](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/DAM/DAM-animals-animaux/WORKAREA/DAM-animals-animaux/text-texte/terr_anima_export_certif_pets_internat_bilingual_1396373316023_eng.pdf)
>   Trilingual - [Canadian International Health Certificate - PDF (193 kb)](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/DAM/DAM-animals-animaux/WORKAREA/DAM-animals-animaux/text-texte/terr_anima_export_certif_pets_internat_trilingual_1396373344430_eng.pdf)
>
> If your destination country accepts this document, have it completed by a veterinarian in Canada and endorsed by an official government veterinarian. There is a fee for this service.
>
> You do not need a Canadian International Health Certificate if you are travelling to countries providing their own health certificates or to countries or zones that have negotiated specific veterinary health certificates with the Canadian Food Inspection Agency (CFIA).
>
> - [List by country/jurisdiction](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/animals/terrestrial-animals/exports/live-animals/health-certificates/pets/eng/1321265624789/1321281361100)
>
> For further information, please contact the [CFIA Office](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/animals/terrestrial-animals/offices/eng/1300462382369) for your province.

PetTravel.com is a source of country requirements for Poland and Germany (and [other countries](https://www.pettravel.com/passportnew.cfm) through which you may transit or visit):

- [Poland](https://www.pettravel.com/immigration/poland.cfm)
- [Germany](https://www.pettravel.com/immigration/Germany.cfm)